# Rails and JSONP

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm dealing with the final construct of my booking system, the payment process.
I have already successfully communicated with the Gateway all the payments data and they proceed to the end, but i'm having problem with the response which is in JSONP, in URL as shown below.
Basically it just request a webpage that i shall interpretate to data decrypting the second value.

```
http://192.168.1.200:3000/en?a=ABCD1234&b=_Op0xtIIrWd93e74s_nuZzVI6Gpj*UiegTJKNTQLqrGI0h_C*0qhnt_X_7VViJU8uIYCZDXajsLCLssq7QMZBfq70X7kNDQ7CDKYY21jaIPPSMFWEIySdz7vR72gJA5Ow8yzK8
```

The Gateway uses for communication between servers JSONP with 2 variables, a & b, i don't care about a, but what i want is b to decrypt it and then to store the data on the db.

The problem is i don't know where to start to create a resource which can accept this kind of urls, so to start working with it.

Thank you for your concerneces

P.S. i'm using rails 4

Comment: I'm a little unclear here... are you trying to parse the response of that URL, or are you trying to parse the parameters of that URL?

Comment: the gateway links to my domain/server with a jsonp url, so i'm trying to be able to make that resource virtually "real" to get the data stored in b, basically i think i need both to parse the response and the parameters...